# How to add external JavaScript and swiper.js files to Nuxt 3 (nuxt.config.ts)?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5, swiper.js, nuxt3

I tried to add an external javascript file to nuxt.config.ts but nuxt 3 didn't load the file.But the CSS files work correctly, Only the script files don't work properly, I did a lot of research but I didn't get the right answer, this question is also asked by other people, please help me very much, thank you very much. version Nuxt 3 : 3.4.1
nuxt.config.ts file:[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVmAP.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5ACH.jpg)

I sent two photos, please see.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)

Answer (score 1):

You should register swiper as a plugin for your Nuxt 3 project. See https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/plugins